# Malloc is interrupted by an unexpected interrupt

Tags: c, embedded, malloc, stm32

I met a strange problem. I use Eclipse Oxygen.2, windows 10, J-linker, STM32L4R5ZI, STM32CubeMX V1.0 ver 4.26.0, arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 227977]

The problem: whenever I want to use the `malloc` function, I end up in `WWDG_IRQHandler()` (`Default_Handler`: `Infinit_Loop`) and never go back from `malloc`.

The Linker script:

```
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 640K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 2048K
}
```

the main function:

```
int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  uint8_t *tab = malloc(100);    

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();      
  HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);      
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7);

  while (1)
  {    
  }    
}
```

The _sbrk:

```
_sbrk(int incr)
{
  extern char _Heap_Begin; // Defined by the linker.
  extern char _Heap_Limit; // Defined by the linker.

  static char* current_heap_end;
  char* current_block_address;

  if (current_heap_end == 0)
    {
      current_heap_end = &_Heap_Begin;
    }

  current_block_address = current_heap_end;

  // Need to align heap to word boundary, else will get
  // hard faults on Cortex-M0. So we assume that heap starts on
  // word boundary, hence make sure we always add a multiple of
  // 4 to it.
  incr = (incr + 3) & (~3); // align value to 4
  if (current_heap_end + incr > &_Heap_Limit)
    {
      // Some of the libstdc++-v3 tests rely upon detecting
      // out of memory errors, so do not abort here.
#if 0
      extern void abort (void);

      _write (1, "_sbrk: Heap and stack collision\n", 32);

      abort ();
#else
      // Heap has overflowed
      errno = ENOMEM;
      return (caddr_t) - 1;
#endif
    }

  current_heap_end += incr;

  return (caddr_t) current_block_address;
}
```

Scripts:
Sections.ld

```
/*
 * Default linker script for Cortex-M (it includes specifics for STM32F[34]xx).
 * 
 * To make use of the multi-region initialisations, define
 * OS_INCLUDE_STARTUP_INIT_MULTIPLE_RAM_SECTIONS for the _startup.c file.
 */

/*
 * The '__stack' definition is required by crt0, do not remove it.
 */
__stack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);

_estack = __stack;  /* STM specific definition */

/*
 * Default stack sizes.
 * These are used by the startup in order to allocate stacks 
 * for the different modes.
 */

__Main_Stack_Size = 1024 ;

PROVIDE ( _Main_Stack_Size = __Main_Stack_Size ) ;

__Main_Stack_Limit = __stack  - __Main_Stack_Size ;

/* "PROVIDE" allows to easily override these values from an 
 * object file or the command line. */
PROVIDE ( _Main_Stack_Limit = __Main_Stack_Limit ) ;

/*
 * There will be a link error if there is not this amount of 
 * RAM free at the end. 
 */
_Minimum_Stack_Size = 256 ;

/*
 * Default heap definitions.
 * The heap start immediately after the last statically allocated 
 * .sbss/.noinit section, and extends up to the main stack limit.
 */
PROVIDE ( _Heap_Begin = _end_noinit ) ;
PROVIDE ( _Heap_Limit = __stack - __Main_Stack_Size ) ;

/* 
 * The entry point is informative, for debuggers and simulators,
 * since the Cortex-M vector points to it anyway.
 */
ENTRY(_start)


/* Sections Definitions */

SECTIONS
{
    /*
     * For Cortex-M devices, the beginning of the startup code is stored in
     * the .isr_vector section, which goes to FLASH. 
     */
    .isr_vector : ALIGN(4)
    {
        FILL(0xFF)

        __vectors_start = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
        __vectors_start__ = ABSOLUTE(.) ; /* STM specific definition */
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))        /* Interrupt vectors */

        KEEP(*(.cfmconfig))         /* Freescale configuration words */   

        /* 
         * This section is here for convenience, to store the
         * startup code at the beginning of the flash area, hoping that
         * this will increase the readability of the listing.
         */
        *(.after_vectors .after_vectors.*)  /* Startup code and ISR */

    } >FLASH

    .inits : ALIGN(4)
    {
        /* 
         * Memory regions initialisation arrays.
         *
         * Thee are two kinds of arrays for each RAM region, one for 
         * data and one for bss. Each is iterated at startup and the   
         * region initialisation is performed.
         * 
         * The data array includes:
         * - from (LOADADDR())
         * - region_begin (ADDR())
         * - region_end (ADDR()+SIZEOF())
         *
         * The bss array includes:
         * - region_begin (ADDR())
         * - region_end (ADDR()+SIZEOF())
         *
         * WARNING: It is mandatory that the regions are word aligned, 
         * since the initialisation code works only on words.
         */

        __data_regions_array_start = .;

        LONG(LOADADDR(.data));
        LONG(ADDR(.data));
        LONG(ADDR(.data)+SIZEOF(.data));

        LONG(LOADADDR(.data_CCMRAM));
        LONG(ADDR(.data_CCMRAM));
        LONG(ADDR(.data_CCMRAM)+SIZEOF(.data_CCMRAM));

        __data_regions_array_end = .;

        __bss_regions_array_start = .;

        LONG(ADDR(.bss));
        LONG(ADDR(.bss)+SIZEOF(.bss));

        LONG(ADDR(.bss_CCMRAM));
        LONG(ADDR(.bss_CCMRAM)+SIZEOF(.bss_CCMRAM));

        __bss_regions_array_end = .;

        /* End of memory regions initialisation arrays. */

        /*
         * These are the old initialisation sections, intended to contain
         * naked code, with the prologue/epilogue added by crti.o/crtn.o
         * when linking with startup files. The standalone startup code
         * currently does not run these, better use the init arrays below.
         */
        KEEP(*(.init))
        KEEP(*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);

        /*
         * The preinit code, i.e. an array of pointers to initialisation 
         * functions to be performed before constructors.
         */
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);

        /*
         * Used to run the SystemInit() before anything else.
         */
        KEEP(*(.preinit_array_sysinit .preinit_array_sysinit.*))

        /* 
         * Used for other platform inits.
         */
        KEEP(*(.preinit_array_platform .preinit_array_platform.*))

        /*
         * The application inits. If you need to enforce some order in 
         * execution, create new sections, as before.
         */
        KEEP(*(.preinit_array .preinit_array.*))

        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);

        . = ALIGN(4);

        /*
         * The init code, i.e. an array of pointers to static constructors.
         */
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
        KEEP(*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP(*(.init_array))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);

        . = ALIGN(4);

        /*
         * The fini code, i.e. an array of pointers to static destructors.
         */
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
        KEEP(*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        KEEP(*(.fini_array))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);

    } >FLASH

    /*
     * For some STRx devices, the beginning of the startup code
     * is stored in the .flashtext section, which goes to FLASH.
     */
    .flashtext : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.flashtext .flashtext.*)  /* Startup code */
    } >FLASH


    /*
     * The program code is stored in the .text section, 
     * which goes to FLASH.
     */
    .text : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.text .text.*)            /* all remaining code */

        /* read-only data (constants) */
        *(.rodata .rodata.* .constdata .constdata.*)        

        *(vtable)                   /* C++ virtual tables */

        KEEP(*(.eh_frame*))

        /*
         * Stub sections generated by the linker, to glue together 
         * ARM and Thumb code. .glue_7 is used for ARM code calling 
         * Thumb code, and .glue_7t is used for Thumb code calling 
         * ARM code. Apparently always generated by the linker, for some
         * architectures, so better leave them here.
         */
        *(.glue_7)
        *(.glue_7t)

    } >FLASH

    /* ARM magic sections */
    .ARM.extab : ALIGN(4)
    {
       *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    } > FLASH

    . = ALIGN(4);
    __exidx_start = .;      
    .ARM.exidx : ALIGN(4)
    {
       *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > FLASH
    __exidx_end = .;

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;
    __etext = .;

    /* MEMORY_ARRAY */
    /*
    .ROarraySection :
    {
        *(.ROarraySection .ROarraySection.*)                          
    } >MEMORY_ARRAY
    */

    /*
     * The secondary initialised data section.
     */
    .data_CCMRAM : ALIGN(4)
    {
       FILL(0xFF)
       *(.data.CCMRAM .data.CCMRAM.*)
       . = ALIGN(4) ;
    } > CCMRAM AT>FLASH

    /* 
     * This address is used by the startup code to 
     * initialise the .data section.
     */
    _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

    /*
     * The initialised data section.
     *
     * The program executes knowing that the data is in the RAM
     * but the loader puts the initial values in the FLASH (inidata).
     * It is one task of the startup to copy the initial values from 
     * FLASH to RAM.
     */
    .data : ALIGN(4)
    {
        FILL(0xFF)
        /* This is used by the startup code to initialise the .data section */
        _sdata = . ;            /* STM specific definition */
        __data_start__ = . ;
        *(.data_begin .data_begin.*)

        *(.data .data.*)

        *(.data_end .data_end.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);

        /* This is used by the startup code to initialise the .data section */
        _edata = . ;            /* STM specific definition */
        __data_end__ = . ;

    } >RAM AT>FLASH

    /*
     * The uninitialised data sections. NOLOAD is used to avoid
     * the "section `.bss' type changed to PROGBITS" warning
     */

    /* The secondary uninitialised data section. */
    .bss_CCMRAM (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.bss.CCMRAM .bss.CCMRAM.*)
    } > CCMRAM

    /* The primary uninitialised data section. */
    .bss (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4)
    {
        __bss_start__ = .;      /* standard newlib definition */
        _sbss = .;              /* STM specific definition */
        *(.bss_begin .bss_begin.*)

        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)

        *(.bss_end .bss_end.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __bss_end__ = .;        /* standard newlib definition */
        _ebss = . ;             /* STM specific definition */
    } >RAM

    .noinit_CCMRAM (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.noinit.CCMRAM .noinit.CCMRAM.*)         
    } > CCMRAM

    .noinit (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4)
    {
        _noinit = .;

        *(.noinit .noinit.*) 

         . = ALIGN(4) ;
        _end_noinit = .;   
    } > RAM

    /* Mandatory to be word aligned, _sbrk assumes this */
    PROVIDE ( end = _end_noinit ); /* was _ebss */
    PROVIDE ( _end = _end_noinit );
    PROVIDE ( __end = _end_noinit );
    PROVIDE ( __end__ = _end_noinit );

    /*
     * Used for validation only, do not allocate anything here!
     *
     * This is just to check that there is enough RAM left for the Main
     * stack. It should generate an error if it's full.
     */
    ._check_stack : ALIGN(4)
    {
        . = . + _Minimum_Stack_Size ;
    } >RAM

    /*
     * The FLASH Bank1.
     * The C or assembly source must explicitly place the code 
     * or data there using the "section" attribute.
     */
    .b1text : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.b1text)                   /* remaining code */
        *(.b1rodata)                 /* read-only data (constants) */
        *(.b1rodata.*)
    } >FLASHB1

    /*
     * The EXTMEM.
     * The C or assembly source must explicitly place the code or data there
     * using the "section" attribute.
     */

    /* EXTMEM Bank0 */
    .eb0text : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.eb0text)                   /* remaining code */
        *(.eb0rodata)                 /* read-only data (constants) */
        *(.eb0rodata.*)
    } >EXTMEMB0

    /* EXTMEM Bank1 */
    .eb1text : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.eb1text)                   /* remaining code */
        *(.eb1rodata)                 /* read-only data (constants) */
        *(.eb1rodata.*)
    } >EXTMEMB1

    /* EXTMEM Bank2 */
    .eb2text : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.eb2text)                   /* remaining code */
        *(.eb2rodata)                 /* read-only data (constants) */
        *(.eb2rodata.*)
    } >EXTMEMB2

    /* EXTMEM Bank0 */
    .eb3text : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.eb3text)                   /* remaining code */
        *(.eb3rodata)                 /* read-only data (constants) */
        *(.eb3rodata.*)
    } >EXTMEMB3


    /* After that there are only debugging sections. */

    /* This can remove the debugging information from the standard libraries */    
    /* 
    DISCARD :
    {
     libc.a ( * )
     libm.a ( * )
     libgcc.a ( * )
     }
     */

    /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
    .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
    .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
    .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
    .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
    .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
    .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
    .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
    /*
     * DWARF debug sections.
     * Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     * of the section so we begin them at 0.  
     */
    /* DWARF 1 */
    .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
    .line           0 : { *(.line) }
    /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
    .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
    .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
    /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
    .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
    .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
    /* DWARF 2 */
    .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
    .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
    .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line) }
    .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
    .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
    .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
    .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
    /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
    .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
    .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
    .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
    .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }    
}
```

STM32L4R5ZI Flash.ld

```
/*
*****************************************************************************
**

**  File        : LinkerScript.ld
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32L4R5ZITx Device with
**                2048KByte FLASH, 640KByte RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed as is, without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
**  (c)Copyright Ac6.
**  You may use this file as-is or modify it according to the needs of your
**  project. Distribution of this file (unmodified or modified) is not
**  permitted. Ac6 permit registered System Workbench for MCU users the
**  rights to distribute the assembled, compiled & linked contents of this
**  file as part of an application binary file, provided that it is built
**  using the System Workbench for MCU toolchain.
**
*****************************************************************************
*/

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x200A0000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x800;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x860; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 640K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 2048K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : 
  { 
  . = ALIGN(8);
  *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
  . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .init_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM



  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Comment: How the symbols from the linker script

Comment: @P__J__ PROVIDE ( _Heap_Begin = _end_noinit ) ;
PROVIDE ( _Heap_Limit = __stack - __Main_Stack_Size ) ;

Long short story: I have no other choice.

Comment: @user, of course you do. `static uint8_t tab[100];` or move it out of main, or define an area in your linker script and provide a symbol, or ...

Comment: also, where do you kick the watchdog? How have you determined it's `malloc` causing the issue?

Comment: @Colin what do you mean by define an area in your linker sciprt..? I am new in it so I may not fully understand. Watchdog is trigered internally, isn't?

Comment: @Colin it is not watchdog. It is a hardfault - they just have the the same handler by default. Sometimes a bit confusing for beginners.

Comment: @Colin How I figured it out that the malloc causes the problem? When I run my program without the malloc it runs. Once I intrudce the malloc it crashes (never goes to the next line).

WWDG_IRQHandler() at startup_stm32l4r5xx.S:132 0x8000370 
<signal handler called>() at 0xfffffff9 
_malloc_r() at 0x8002188 
main() at main.c:105 0x8001f3c

Comment: @user it is a hardfault do not worry too mucha bout the handler name. Show **full** linker script

Comment: @Colin in the Cube generated ones they are all handled by the same function. There are no "different versions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the STM32L4R5ZI_Flash script and remove the sections script (so I use only one script now).

Unfortunately, _Heap_Begin and _Heap_Limit take valuses which I cannot explain, but at least it works.

The changed script:

```
/*
*****************************************************************************
**

**  File        : LinkerScript.ld
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32L4R5ZITx Device with
**                2048KByte FLASH, 640KByte RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed as is, without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
**  (c)Copyright Ac6.
**  You may use this file as-is or modify it according to the needs of your
**  project. Distribution of this file (unmodified or modified) is not
**  permitted. Ac6 permit registered System Workbench for MCU users the
**  rights to distribute the assembled, compiled & linked contents of this
**  file as part of an application binary file, provided that it is built
**  using the System Workbench for MCU toolchain.
**
*****************************************************************************
*/

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x200A0000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size  = 0x2000;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x4000; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 640K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 2048K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : 
  { 
  . = ALIGN(8);
  *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
  . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .init_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM

  _Heap_Begin = __bss_end__ ;
  _Heap_Limit = _Heap_Begin + _Min_Heap_Size;

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not necessarily ending up in the WWDG_IRQ function.  You are ending up in the default interrupt handler function which is the infinite loop.  This function is the destination for many of the processor exceptions set up by STMCubeMX.  You will end up in the same place if you get a bus fault interrupt due to accessing a non existent memory location.  I have seen on a number of debuggers that they will say that you are in the WWDG_IRQ function regardless of which interrupt/exception actually took you there.

I would expect that in your malloc function you are attempting to access an illegal address and generating a processor exception.  Single step through the function and you can localise the problem.

Comment: I know, and agree.
I cannt go step into the instruction. What I do it:
1. breakpoint in the malloc line
2. click Resume
3. end up in the default handler. On the other hande in step nr 2 i can also go for step into but the result is the same. I cannot see next step after malloc. Maybe the library is wrong (stdlib.h from GNU Tools ARM Embedded)?